# Bootstrap 4 close button not working django

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CErby.png)I have a close button on my alert but when I click on it it doesn't close. I have seen similar people with the same problem but none of the solutions have worked for me

This is what I currently have

```
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you’ve loaded the alert plugin, or the compiled Bootstrap JavaScript?

Comment: You have used class `alert-dismissible` which is incorrect and it should be `alert-dismissable`. I have also share a code snippet as well please check it and correct the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Aslamkhan, you were right and your code snippet works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="alert alert-danger fade show alert-dismissable">Alert title is here <span class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</span></div>
```

Please check the code snippet and correct your code accordingly.